# Conditional Rewrite of URLs that contain an exclamation mark !

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Both

```
domain.com/blog/post/2011/01/25/This-Is-The-Post-Title!.aspx
domain.com/blog/post/2011/01/25/This-Is-The-Post-Title.aspx
```

need to be redirected to

```
domain.com/blog/2011/01/25/this-is-the-post-title
```

The following rule works for urls without an exclamation mark, but I can't seem to get a condition to strip the ! from the urls if it exists.

```
RewriteRule ^blog/post(.*).aspx$ /blog${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line before your rule:

```
RewriteRule (.*)!(.*) $1$2 [N,DPI]
```

This will **remove ALL** `!` characters in URL (path part only, query string is not affected). You can modify it to only apply to blog article titles only -- up to you.

**Be careful though** -- it uses `[N]` flag which causes Apache to start rewrite again from topmost rule in order to remove all occurrences, otherwise only first occurrence will be replaced (if there are more than one `!`). Therefore I recommend putting this rule *somewhere on the top*.

**Alternative for `[N]` flag** would be having this rule without this flag but multiple times one after another.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n

Answer (score 0):

I was able to leverage LazyOne's answer and ended up with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)!(.*) $1$2 [N,DPI,E=ep:yes]
RewriteCond %{ENV:ep} ^yes$
RewriteRule (.*) https://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Works perfectly!